# Reporting user on Django error reports

Tags: python, django

I use Django's built-in feature for sending me error reports every time there's a 500 on the server. I use the `include_html` feature to get the richer version.

I'd really like the logged-in user, if one is logged in, to be sent as part of the report. I know I can deduce it myself using the session id, but I'd really prefer it be sent so I won't have to look it up every time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of [Custom Error Reports](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#custom-error-reports). settings.py You'll need to make your own exception reporter class. I haven't used it with the `include_html` feature though.

This is an example of what you'll need to do.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.debug import SafeExceptionReporterFilter


class CustomExceptionReporterFilter(SafeExceptionReporterFilter):

    def get_request_repr(self, request):
        result = u"User Info: \n"
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = request.user
            result += u"\nUser Id: {}".format(user.id)
        else:
            result += u"\nUser Id: Not logged in"
        result += super(CustomExceptionReporterFilter, self).get_request_repr(request)
        return result
```